# Getting details of the subscriber in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, email, subscriber

Is it possible to download or retrieve only the subscriber details using wordpress.i can see the list of users along with the subscriber in an admin page.but i want to get only the details(email address)of the subscriber.Is there is any code for that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From reading your question, it sounds like you just want to scrape up email addresses.  That actually has me a bit reluctant to answer, but I can see why you might need to do this (in the case of a site migration, for example).

WordPress does defines a function specifically for retrieving a list of your users that also returns their email addresses: [`wp_list_authors();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_authors).